# Как объединить вывод из двух колонок в один?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT a, b FROM examle WHERE ...
```

Требуется чтобы результат был выведен в одну общую колонку, не склеен, а именно новой строкой
Сейчас условно выводится 2 строки с

```
a = 1, b = 2
a = 3, b = 4
```

Нужно получить колонку D со строками

```
d
-----
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: CTE есть? `select a,b,row_number()` в цте. Потом из него второй цте `select rn, a as x,1 as ab union select rn,b,2` потом общий селект `select x order by rn, ab`

Comment: @teran Ему вроде не надо нумеровать, только значения - так что можно сразу UNION.

Comment: @Akina просто у него результат отсортирован по строкам. Если не надо, то просто `union(all)`, да.

Comment: А что собственно мешает сортировать объединённый набор? да и как-то автор не настаивает на сортировке, вроде бы, это данные такие..